# Pyparsing transforms parsed \x00 into \\x00

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I need to compare a byte string such as `b'\x08\x09'` for example to a string specified in a text file that is going to be parsed. Since the characters are not going to be pure alphanumeric, my idea was to specify it the same way Python does, meaning using \x..
So my file contains a text line such as `value_a=\x08\x09`. When I parse it however I obtain the string `'\\x08\\x09'`.

How can write the parser and/or the parsed text file so that the parsing result would be either `b'\x08\x09'` or `'\x08\x09'`?

Comment: you may need to instruct that the file is binary when you open it .. however, it may be that you're only seeing the representation of the file incorrectly

Comment: `foo.encode().decode('unicode_escape')` or `'\\x08\\x09'.encode().decode('unicode_escape')`. To transform it to a `bytes` object just add another `.encode()`. `'\\x08\\x09'.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode()`

Comment: @Axe319 That should be an answer. Also, you need to be careful about the encoding. `.encode().decode('unicode_escape')` encodes as UTF-8, then decodes as Latin-1, according to the docs. And if you want `\xab` to become the bytes `b'\xab'`, you'd better use `.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1')` – but it's kind of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that data are safe (eg. it's not user input) you can use eval hack

```
text = '\\x08\\x09'
value = eval(f"b'{text}'")
print(value)
```

Anyway safer approach would be split it by \ and convert bytes individually.

EDIT: comment by @axe319 with unicode_escape ecoding seems to be the best result. Use it. Keeping this answer as illustration how many ways can lead to result.

Comment: You could use `ast.literal_eval` rather than the unsafe `eval`

Answer (score 0):

I think the presence of backslashes in your strings is throwing you off. To work with strings with backslashes, use the raw string literal syntax (leading 'r' before the quotes). See the difference here:

```
>>> # python evaluates \x08 as chr(8), the backspace character
>>> # and \x09 as chr(9), the tab character
>>> print([ord(c) for c in "\x08\x09"])
[8, 9]
>>> # in a raw string literal, python treats '\' like any other character
>>> print([ord(c) for c in r"\x08\x09"])
[92, 120, 48, 56, 92, 120, 48, 57]
```

So I suspect you are defining your search string as something like:

```
search = Literal("\x08\x09")
```

Instead, define it as:

```
search = Literal(r"\x08\x09")
```